# How to quicky update images in java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I want to know what is the fastest way to display and update images in JAVA. I'm receiving a series of images continuously from a socket and i want to display them in real time. I'm currently using a Jlabel inside a JFrame.

```
void refreshScreen(BufferedImage bufImg)
{
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bufImg));
frame.repaint();
frame.getContentPane().repaint();
}
```

However this is extremely slow and takes 15-20 seconds to update even on my fast computer. What would be the ideal way to do this?

Comment: No need to call repaint if a JLabel's Icon changes. The key for you is to read in the images in a background thread, create your ImageIcon and set your label's Icon on the Swing event thread. Note your speed has nothing to do with Swing and all to do with transmitting the images through a Socket.

Answer (score 1):

The problem would not be updating the image. When you set the Icon of a JLabel it will repaint itself immediately.

The problem would probably be in receiving the image over the socket (the speed of you computer has no effect here). You must make sure that the code that uses the socket does not block the Event Dispatch Thread as this will prevent the GUI from repainting itself. So you need to use a separate Thread for the Socket connection.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: I'm calling refreshScreen() each time i receive an image in the socket. I see that the images come to the socket quickly but there is a lag in displaying it. So i guess socket isn't the bottleneck here.Its the displaying of the image.

Comment: @user2600028, the problem is not in the displaying of the image. That will happen immediately once the image is fully loaded. As I suggested earlier, you must be blocking the EDT so it can't repaint the image. Read the tutorial.